# How to filter html table td attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, attributes

I want to filter the td attribute in my HTML table, but it does not return any results. I just want to show the tr data-value attribute that contains the value. does not return the result as I want now

"I am sorry for this English"

```js
function Search() {
  var value = $('#searchbar-4').val().toLowerCase();
  if (value != "") {
    $("#grid-4 tbody tr").each(
      function() {
        var r = $(this).find("td[data-value*='" + value + "']");
        if (r > -1) {
          $(this).show();
        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
  } else {
    ...
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb1" class="all-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="td-fixed">Facility name</th>
      <th class="td-fixed2">Phone #</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Speciality</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="5" class="td-fixed">CCC</td>
      <td data-value="4" class="td-fixed2">00001111</td>
      <td data-value="2">Amsterdam</td>
      <td data-value="6">GGG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="8" class="td-fixed">JJJ</td>
      <td dat-value="9" class="td-fixed2">55544444</td>
      <td data-value="55">London</td>
      <td data-value="15">MMM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="14" class="td-fixed">AAA</td>
      <td data-value="19" class="td-fixed2">33332222</td>
      <td data-value="20">Paris</td>
      <td data-value="18">RRR</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not usually one for criticizing people's English skills, but I can't understand this at all. If anybody can decode this, please edit the question.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you need. Your code is also confusing. The Id's are not present in the HTML code

Comment: I want to filter the td attribute value in my HTML table

Comment: he wants to hide every tr that does not have td with given attribute value

Comment: can you edit the question to give the expected result?

Comment: yes @nAviD I just want to show the tr that contains the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did, but I'm not sure that's the best way.

```js
function FilterRows(event) {
            var value = event.value.toLowerCase();
            var rows = $('#tb1 tbody tr');
            rows.hide();
            rows.each(function() {
                var row = $(this);
                var cells = $(this).find('td');
                cells.each(function() {
                    var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
                    if (val) {
                        if (val.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                            row.show();
                        }
                    }

                });
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onkeyup="FilterRows(this)" placeholder="Ara" />

<table id="tb1" class="all-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="td-fixed">Facility name</th>
        <th class="td-fixed2">Phone #</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Speciality</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-value="CCC" class="td-fixed">CCC</td>
        <td data-value="00001111" class="td-fixed2">00001111</td>
        <td data-value="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</td>
        <td data-value="GGG">GGG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-value="JJJ" class="td-fixed">JJJ</td>
        <td data-value="55544444" class="td-fixed2">55544444</td>
        <td data-value="London">London</td>
        <td data-value="MMM">MMM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-value="AAA" class="td-fixed">AAA</td>
        <td data-value="33332222" class="td-fixed2">33332222</td>
        <td data-value="Paris">Paris</td>
        <td data-value="RRR">RRR</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows, hide them, filter by given value and show the filtered list:

```js
function filterRows(myVal) {
  var rows = $('#tb1 tbody tr');
  rows.hide();
  var filteredRows = rows.filter(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td');
    return cells.filter(function(){
      return $(this).data('value') === myVal;
    }).length > 0;
  });
  filteredRows.show();
 }
 filterRows(55);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb1" class="all-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="td-fixed">Facility name</th>
      <th class="td-fixed2">Phone #</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Speciality</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="5" class="td-fixed">CCC</td>
      <td data-value="4" class="td-fixed2">00001111</td>
      <td data-value="2">Amsterdam</td>
      <td data-value="6">GGG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="8" class="td-fixed">JJJ</td>
      <td data-value="9" class="td-fixed2">55544444</td>
      <td data-value="55">London</td>
      <td data-value="15">MMM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-value="14" class="td-fixed">AAA</td>
      <td data-value="19" class="td-fixed2">33332222</td>
      <td data-value="20">Paris</td>
      <td data-value="18">RRR</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: call function filterRows(9); but now show 2. and 3. line(tr)

Comment: yes but thats due to the typo in the cells attribute. You wrote `dat-value` instead of `data-value`  and i copied that to my snippet id did correct it in my answer

Comment: i mean not return any result for filterRows(9);

Comment: It does though `filterRows(9)` shows the row `[[JJJ][55544444][London][MMM]]`

Comment: ok but i want to like $( "td[data-value]:contains('9')" ) return two row

Comment: I can only for number true result but not run alphanumeric
function FilterRows(event) {
       var value = event.value.toLowerCase();
       var rows = $('#netoloji-grid-@app.CIID tbody tr');
       rows.hide();
       var filteredRows = rows.filter(function() {
       var cells = $(this).find('td');
       if (cells.attr('data-value').indexOf(value) > -1) {
              $(this).show();
       } else {
              $(this).hide();
       }
       });
       filteredRows.show();
}

Comment: Why would you want it to return 2 rows ? You only have 1 row containing a cell with `data-value="9"`.

Comment: Search for (mag) return lines data-value="xmag", data-value="magq", data-value="1mag2"

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: === instead of contains